# Код не работает и я не знаю почему

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
$('#btn').on('click' , ()=>{
  $('#btn').toggleClass('red')
})
```

```css
h1{
  color: #000;
}

.red{
  color: #F00;
}

.green{
  color: #0F0;
}

.blue{
  color: #00F;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 id="btn">
  Привет 
</h1>
```

Comment: что именно не работает?

Comment: А ваш браузер [поддерживает стрелочные функции](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C_%D1%81_%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8)?
Когда вы подключаете свой код и JQ?